# How to declare a sbt plugin?

Tags: eclipse, sbt

I have cloned sbteclipse.I am reading scala-sbt tutorial,says:

```
If your project is in directory hello, and you’re adding sbt-site plugin to the build definition, create hello/project/site.sbt
```

I am in /home/mil directory,and sbteclipse is in the same directory.Inside sbteclipse is project directory with plugins.sbt

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-sbt" % "scripted-plugin" % sbtVersion.value

addSbtPlugin("com.github.gseitz" % "sbt-release" % "1.0.3")

addSbtPlugin("org.scalariform" % "sbt-scalariform" % "1.6.0")
```

Should I edit this file or not?How to declare plugin in oreder to enable eclipse to recognize them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, SBT plugins has to be defined in the `project` subfolder of your project's root. SBT aggregates definitions from all files with `.sbt` extension, so it doesn't really matter if you call it `plugins.sbt` or `site.sbt`. It's also fine to have multiple `.sbt` files.

So in your particular case, either add that plugin to the existing `project/plugins.sbt`, or follow the tutorial and create a new file, `project/site.sbt`, and add the plugin there.

P.S. this rule of searching and aggregating definitions from all `.sbt` files applies not only to meta-build (`project` directory), but also for the build itself. It might make sense to split big build definitions into multiple `.sbt` files. E.g. we have `build.sbt` for main definitions (library dependencies, etc.) and `docker.sbt` for Docker definitions.